# Why is the link going to the side of my screen, if my max-screen size is 100%?

Tags: html, css

So I'm making a website with HTML & CSS, and I want to have 2 navigation bars (1 for the Register and Log In for e.g.) and the other one for "Home", "Projects", "Partners", etc., so I've done:

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

* {
  font-family: 'Shippori Antique B1', sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: .3s;
  color: #fff;
}

a:hover {
  transition: .3s;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.navigation {
  color: #fff;
  background: #006CFF;
  padding: 10px;
}

.top-navigation {
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #0084FF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a3f36ff0b4.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Shippori+Antique+B1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/logo.png" />

<div class="top-navigation">
  <a href="register.html">Register</a>
  <a href="register.html">Log In</a>
</div>

<div class="navigation"></div>
```

And for some reason my div class "top-navigation" 'Log In' link goes off the screen, now I know I can fix that just by adding "float: right;" to the CSS part of "top-navigation", but then for some reason, the main "navigation" div class will disappear.

Anyone can assist me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `width: 100%;` from `.top-navigation` and your items will show up as you intended.

```
.top-navigation {
    text-align: right; 
    padding: 15px;
    background: #0084FF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the padding is pushing the content out, I removed the padding it worked.

I tried to remove the 100% and it worked too!

```
* {
    font-family: 'Shippori Antique B1', sans-serif;
}

html, body {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: .3s;
    color: #fff;
}

a:hover {
    transition: .3s;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.navigation {
    color: #fff;
    background: #006CFF;
    padding: 10px;
}

.top-navigation {
    text-align: right;
    padding: 15px;
    background: #0084FF;
}
```

Comment: Yea I just tried it, it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to that element to include the `padding` in the 100% `width`

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

* {
    font-family: 'Shippori Antique B1', sans-serif;
}

html, body {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: .3s;
    color: #fff;
}

a:hover {
    transition: .3s;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.navigation {
    color: #fff;
    background: #006CFF;
    padding: 10px;
}

.top-navigation {
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    background: #0084FF;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Website</title>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a3f36ff0b4.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Shippori+Antique+B1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/logo.png"/>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="top-navigation">
        
            <a href="register.html">Register</a>
      <a href="register.html">Log In</a>
            
        </div>
    
    <div class="navigation">
    
        
        
    </div>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works!

Answer (score 0):

These settings make `.top-navigation` 30px wider than the body:

```
.top-navigation {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

By using `body {overflow-x: hidden}`, you effectively cut off 30px of the `.top-navigation` div. You have a few options to correct this, the most simple being to add:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This will make the 100% measurement inclusive of the div's padding and is general best-practice. You could also use `.top-navigation {width: calc(100% - 30px);}`, but you'll likely continue to run into the same issue with other elements.

For more information on box-sizing, check out [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

Comment: Ok, thank you. Works! :)